# How to get only level 0 menu in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, category, topmenu

How to get only level 0 menu in Magento 2?

```
<?php $columnsLimit = $block->getColumnsLimit() ?: 0; ?>
<?php $_menu = $block->getHtml('level-top', 'submenu', $columnsLimit) ?>
```

give all menu items including submenu. I want only level 0 menu. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for step by step implementation refer this [link](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-frontend-how-to-call-category-collection-on-home-page), for [github code](https://github.com/ibnab/magento2-home-categories)

for only show level 0 categories your template look like

```
<?php
$categories = $this->getStoreCategories(true,false,true);
$categoryHelper = $this->getCategoryHelper();
?>
<ul>
<?php
foreach($categories as $category):
     if (!$category->getIsActive()) {
        continue;
     }
?>
<li><a href="<?php echo $categoryHelper->getCategoryUrl($category) ?>"><?php echo $category->getName() ?></a></li>
<?php   
endforeach;
?>
</ul>
```